# MaxWebConfigFileSizeInKB and IIS 10

Tags: iis, web-config, registrykey, iis-10

I am using a Web application with a web.config file larger than 250KB on IIS 10. In IIS 8.5 and below the registry key [HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\InetStp\Configuration\MaxWebConfigFileSizeInKB (REG_DWORD)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/954864) could be set to allow web.configs to be larger than 250KB.
However it seems that this registry key is not read by IIS 10 any longer.

Does anyone know if this key should still work on IIS 10 or how to use config files larger than 250KB in combination with IIS 10?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change maximum allowed configuration file size \[IIS Express 10/Windows 10\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37111764/change-maximum-allowed-configuration-file-size-iis-express-10-windows-10)

Answer (score 3):

I forgot to set the 32 bit version registry key,
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\Configuration\MaxWebConfigFileSizeInKB  (REG_DWORD)
It works now,

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of your registry settings, because I'm unable to get this to work for IIS Express 10 on Windows 10 no matter what I try. :)

Comment: @TedNyberg i am also unable to get this to work... Did you found the solution?

Comment: @JernejPirc Yes, I've added an answer for IIS Express.

Answer (score 1):

For **IIS Express** on Windows 10 you need to set the **MaxWebConfigFileSizeInKB** value in the registry here: `HKLM/HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\IISExpress\10.0\mimic\Configuration`.

[Change maximum allowed configuration file size [IIS Express 10/Windows 10]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37111764/change-maximum-allowed-configuration-file-size-iis-express-10-windows-10)