# Maximum size of web.config in iis 10

Tags: iis, sitecore

One of our sites has a long web.config - a little over the default max size for a web.config.

In windows 8 there was a registry key for the maximum allowed size of the web.config.

What is the setting in iis 10 (windows 10) to change this?

Thanks,

Ian

Comment: Have you tried same registry keys as for windows 8?

Comment: Thank you, it seems you need to add the configuration key as well as the item. Works a treat thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend you to move Sitecore configuration out of Web.config file like it was done it latest Sitecore versions:

```
<sitecore configSource="App_Config\Sitecore.config"/>
```

It is more convenient and you should not change your registry.

Answer (score 1):

Although I do agree with Anton that moving parts to get the config smaller is the best solution, you can find an answer in this post:
[MaxWebConfigFileSizeInKB and IIS 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32329067/maxwebconfigfilesizeinkb-and-iis-10)

> HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\InetStp\Configuration\MaxWebConfigFileSizeInKB
> (REG_DWORD)
>
> HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\Configuration\MaxWebConfigFileSizeInKB
> (REG_DWORD)

Did not test this myself ;)

Comment: I don't have Configuration branch under InetStp. That's why I have doubts.

Comment: Thank you, the configuration key didn't exist so I didn't realise that it was an addable option.

Comment: I've added the key and it doesn't help