# Change maximum allowed configuration file size [IIS Express 10/Windows 10]

Tags: iis, windows-10, iis-express, iis-8

After adding multiple entries to a **redirect map** in a linked config file, I get the following error on **IIS Express 10** on Windows 10 (64 bit, but IIS Express is running 32-bit):

"**Can not read configuration file because it exceed the maximum file size**"

I've tried adding a **Configuration** key to the registry, setting a **MaxWebConfigFileSizeInKB** value of 512 under *HKLM/Software/Microsoft/IISExpress/10.0/mimic/Configuration*:

[image: Regedit]

Any idea on how to enable configuration files larger than 250 KB for IIS Express on Windows 10? Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, this is what saved me: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/amb/2013/01/07/iis-express-8-and-large-web-config-files-cannot-read-configuration-file-because-it-exceeds-the-maximum-file-size-error-message/

Basically, I had to add the the **MaxWebConfigFileSizeInKB** value under:
*HKLM/HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\IISExpress\10.0\mimic\Configuration*